# Who wants to learn set theory?

Tags: set-theory, self-learning

So set theory is something I really want to learn. I found [this document](http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/set_theory.pdf) that I really like, except the fact that it doesn't prove all of it's theorems in with a lot of detail (a lot of times they say something is true and use it in the proof without proving said thing is true, at least so far). I was hoping to find someone (or a group of people) that were interested in learning set theory and would like to read and discuss this document with me so that we both/all may learn from it better. If anyone is interested just shoot me an email at masondeanm@aol.com.

Also, if you're reading this and you think know a way for me to learn set theory on my own that is much better than the document I posted above, please let me know!

Comment: I'm happy to see that even though most of this question is off-topic, Set Theory has so much love that the question has been up voted twice so far. **Edit:** And now, seeing that there is a chapter named *"There is nothing real about the real numbers"* in the link provided, I too up voted.

Comment: This seems related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99198/how-do-i-find-partners-for-study

Comment: This "question" appears to be off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: There exists [Set Theory chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2318). It used to be relatively active, although there is almost no activity there nowadays. But asking there or in the main chatroom is also a possibility when you stumble upon some problem. (And, of course, so is asking the question on the main site.)

Comment: Although it's off-topic, this is admittedly better than the run-of-the-mill blatant homework question with no attempt at civility. To augment this resource, I also recommend: https://www.math.ku.edu/~roitman/SetTheory.pdf. Happy studying.

Comment: Could someone please clarify why this is "off topic" and should be taken down. "it is not a question" is technically not true because I'm asking if anyone would like to learn this with me.

Comment: Mason, you can also ask who is selling a used Kindle Fire. Yes, it's a question, but not one on topic. This site is not meant for arranging study groups, it is meant for asking (more or less) specific questions about mathematics. You can ask set theoretical questions here, that's great. But asking "Who wants to study with me?" is not really a question which is on-topic here.

Comment: Okay, I understand now.