# How to organize math study groups online for long-distance collaboration?

Tags: soft-question, math-software, online-resources

How to organize math study groups online for long-distance collaboration? For example, how to organize a study group to:

- Effectively go through a textbook,
- Taking notes (not necessarily collaboratively),
- Organizing time, exercises,
- Publishing solutions to exercises and reviewing these solutions?

Comment: Somewhat similar past question: [How do I find partners for study?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/99198)

Comment: addition:
I believe this question is on topic just like questions like: [Chatting about mathematics (with real-time LaTeX rendering)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81365/chatting-about-mathematics-with-real-time-latex-rendering)

Comment: It is not quite clear why this was asked here.  Not everything connected to mathematics is on topic.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez i believe this is directly related, as it is about studying mathematics, there also similar questions like the one Martin mentioned http://math.stackexchange.com/q/99198

Comment: Not everything of interest to people doing or studying math is on topic. The standard example is sex, which likely interests a lot of them and which here is really out of place.

Comment: You may try asking at http://academia.stackexchange.com/ (I am not sure if it may be "moved" or if it needs re-asking)

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires i don't think they will consider it on-topic... unless i'm proven wrong

Answer (score 5):

From my experience running computational research projects between people in my research group (in the UK) and with our collaborators in Singapore we tend to use a few tools.

*Sharelatex.com / Dropbox with Latex files*: Writing notes for maths is easiest in latex. I'm not sure if you already use it but if not its a mark up language which allows you to easily add mathematical and scientific notation. It is almost exclusively used in the research community and there are a ton of tutorials online. Notes and updates are well presented and easy for others to go through.

*Slack:* As we are working in collaboration, or in your case studying together, it can be really useful to have a chat space dedicated to the study group. Facebook chat / groups and whatsapp messages proved to be a nightmare for me before and slack is easy to use and free! You can also use the calendar integrations etc.

*Speaking Together:* Even though we are often based on different continents a voice conversation is infinitely better than just text. Of course this depends on the size of the group but I tend to call my collaborators on a regular basis and they call one another too.

I realise this isn't exactly a study group setting but I think its similar enough?

Comment: thanks for your answer, will give you the bounty as there not much choice (; i'm always open to more suggestions btw

Comment: I'll keep an ear out and ask the other guys in my group if they have any other ideas that might be useful for you :) Thanks for the bounty I wasn't expecting it!