# Where could I find a math pen pal?

Tags: education

I'm a high school student. I love mathematics and I read a lot of maths books. I always like to discuss some mathematical problems with others.

But unfortunately, there aren't anyone in my school tending to truly love mathematics, they just care about the exams and they often ignore me when I'm talking mathematics with them.

This maybe because they can't understand what I'm talking about. So I often feel bloody lonely, it's painful. Could anyone help me? I wanna find a pen pal to communicate with each other.

Comment: This older question is, to some limited extent, related: [How do I find partners for study?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/99198)

Comment: Yes,I wanna find a partner for study,but my age is a big problem.

Comment: As mentioned also in some other comments, quite a few users of this site visit chat. You might have a look at [List of chatrooms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26814) on meta.

Comment: OK,I'll work on it.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just got this question as a review audit, and suggested the chatrooms, and failed the audit. Sigh.

Answer (score 8):

A few ideas:

**Reach out to a local (or not) university or college**.  You can do this in a few ways.  The first is to contact something like an admissions department or an outreach department.  Depending on where in the world you live, the university/college may have one or both of these.  Outreach is better, since their job is to connect people in the institution with people outside of it.  This may be math students, but it may be a professor as well.  Local is best since you can in theory go and speak with the person directly some times, but if there is nothing local near you then you can reach out across the globe.  Where are you located?

**Reach out to a math teacher at your school**.  If you know someone you really like, then that person would be a good starting point.  They may have contacts at other schools who can look around for you, or they may serve directly as your mentor.  If you're looking for a student and not an instructor, this is probably the best way.

**Go to reddit**.  Stack exchange is a question/answer site, so discussions are often discouraged.  Reddit, however, is an open discussion site where lively conversation can happen.

Comment: Indeed, discussions are discouraged on the main site but wouldn't it be suitable to discuss on [Chat StackExchange](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=people&page=1&host=math.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I'm sure it would be, but reddit is a site designed for prolonged discussion on a topic where people often surf the main site, rather than the chat board.  It's probably a better forum, but that doesn't mean it's the only option

Comment: The use of "maths" and "bloody lonely" says UK or India.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII What about Singapore, where I live?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: I was actually going to say "and other places influenced by the UK." But, with one billion people, statistically it might be India. :)

Comment: In fact,I have found my math teachers,but they have no idea to help me.And also,they can't understand what I say.Maybe what I learn beyond their professional knowledge.Meanwhile,one of my math teachers looks down on me just because I make a simple mistake.

Comment: @ToneyLiang: if your math teachers don't understand what you say, then it may be that you need to spend more time learning to effectively communicate your ideas.  Part of the process of mathematical education lies in communication as much as it does being amazed by concepts.  Perhaps use that as an opportunity to practice before you get a pen pal, so that you can maximize your discussion with someone new

Comment: In fact,I express my ideas clearly.But my teachers just haven't heard of the mathematical concepts that I say.So they have no idea what I'm talking about.Although they don't know what I say,one of my teachers encourages me to keep on reading maths books,she appreciates me.

Comment: On Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/theydidthemath/